# How can I persist this state after page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi everyone I am struggling to find a way to persist the value of my state after page refresh. Currently I have the value stored in local Storage and I try many solutions to make the user stay logged after page reload still did not work. Every time when I refresh to page I got sign out, I will really appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

**Core.ts:**

```
 class Core {
      agv: typeof agv;
      auth: Auth;
      workflow: WorkflowApi;
      graphql: GraphQLSdk;
      fleetState: Stream<FleetState>;
      taskList: Stream<TaskList>;
      zoneList: Stream<ZoneList>;

  configuration = getConfiguration();

  url: string;

  constructor(options: Options) {
    const auth = getAuth(options);
    const graphqlUrl = `${options.host}/graphql`;
    const graphql = getSdk(new GraphQLClient(graphqlUrl, { fetch: authMiddleware({ auth, fetch: options.fetch }) }));

    const streamContext = {
      ...options,
      headers: getAuthHeaders(auth),
      getSites: () => auth.session.value?.sites || [],
    };

    this.auth = auth;
    this.workflow = getWorkflowApi({ auth }) ;
    this.graphql = graphql;
    this.fleetState = fleetState.call({
      ...options,
      headers: getAuthHeaders(auth),
      getSites: () => auth.session.value?.sites || [],
    });

    this.configuration.map.fetch = this.configuration.map.fetch.bind(async () => {
      const site = auth.session.value.sites[0];
      return graphql.map({ site }).then(({ map }) => map);
    });

    this.taskList = taskList.call(streamContext);
    this.zoneList = zoneList.call(streamContext);

    this.agv = {
      ...agv,
      graphql,
      map: this.configuration.map,
      getSites: () => auth.session.value?.sites || [],
    } as typeof agv;

    auth.session.listen(session => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session));
      console.log(session);
      if (session) {
    this.configuration.map.fetch();
      }
    });
  }
}

export { Core };
```

Comment: I see where the session is persisted ***to*** localStorage. Is there any place where the code is initializing ***from*** localStorage?

Comment: One question , just out of curiosity on that subject Drew, is there a way to make global objects that are hidden from the user in react/typescript?   For example, ASP Classic uses a session object that can not be accessed by the user directly (ie read in Chrome Inspect etc)

Comment: easleyfixed - no, you can somehow obfuscate it, but it will be visible in inspect

Comment: @easleyfixed You're talking about server-side storage. A session is just a unique id that points to some data on your server

Comment: @DrewReese thank for your input, I just read some doc on how to set the value to localstorage but I still don't get how to save that value until the user decide to log out. Any clarification will be much appreciated thanks. Do you refer on localstorage.getIten() when you say initialize?

Comment: What does `getAuth` do? It appears to return an `auth` value that is used. Is the `auth.session` that is persisted what you need to restore, or is there something else in the `auth` object/reference that holds the authentication "state"? Yes, when you initialize from localStorage you will use localStorage.getItem.

Comment: Ah yes, Server Side Session Objects is what I was talking about, and yeah it is an ID to point to the actual values on the server.  I just wondered what other options other languages had so that users can't just right click and start script kidding your variables around.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: It is the value of auth.session I need to persist. When I login I get the value in localstorage but after page refresh that value disappear and get me back in the login page again

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also ask for an [edit] to include the `getAuth` function as part of your [mcve].

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I edited the question as you suggested and added what the getAuth function does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the session is persisted to localStorage as follows

```js
auth.session.listen(session => {
  window.localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session));
  ...
})
```

Then I think you can initialize from localStorage in `getAuth` as follows

```js
function getAuth({ host, fetch }: Dependencies) {
  const session = getEventEmitter<Session | null>({
    initialValue: JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("session")),
  });

  ...
```

If there is no session persisted in state then `null` is the value of the expression and returned as `initialValue`.

Comment: @saygas Welcome, glad this seems to have resolved your issue. Cheers and good luck!